# override the "=" operator in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a class that has a method:

```
def value=(valueIN)
  some code
end
```

and this does exactly what I want when I do:

```
(class instance).value="new data"
```

It seems like it would be cleaner if I could just override the `=` for this class so I do not have to do `value=`. First, I tried:

```
def =(valueIN)
  some code
end
```

but this gave me an error, so then I tried:

```
def self=(valueIN)
  some code
end
```

This does not cause an error, but it does not work when I do:

```
(class instance)="new data"
```

Is the assignment something that is not changeable at the class level? If this cannot be done, its not really a big deal, but I was hoping I am missing something basic.

Comment: Thankfully, you cannot do that. If you could, the code would become a real bitch to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do this. When you write `foo = bar`, you're just assigning a variable, not calling any method. It's only `something.foo = bar` that desugars to a method call, and just like everywhere else, the receiver of that method call is the thing before the dot.

Comment: alright so "=" is not a method of some parent class but is an operator, guess that makes sense really.  I guess I just got used to expecting everything to be overridable on the fly I kind of figured everything was a method of a class somewhere :)

Answer (score 4):

`=` is not an operator in Ruby that could be overwritten. The trick Ruby  plays (with us) is, that

```
self.value = "Me"
self.value= "You"
self.value=("He")
```

are all interpreted the same, so that you are free to use the version you like most. Because these are all method calls, you can define or overwrite how `value=` with one argument should work.

It is an idiom to use that *only* for assigning attributes of objects, but Ruby allows you to use it where you want.

So no chance to overwrite the `=` operator (which I think is a good idea).

Comment: Those are not the all same. The first two call `self#value=`, while the latter two just set the local variable `value`.

Comment: Thank's for that, I will correct it. This is exactly one of the things newcomers don't understand ... :-(

Answer (score 1):

`=` is interpreted in one of the two ways depending on the context.

- part of a method of the form `foo=`
- variable assignment operator

You can define your own method in the form `foo=`, in which case `=` is preceded by an alphabet, but you cannot redefine the variable assignment operator `=`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to provide a setter method for a class-level value, you can do so using something like this:

```
class MyClass
  def self.my_class_attribute=(value)
    @my_class_attribute = value
  end
end
```

Then you can assign to it like so:

```
MyClass.my_class_attribute = "new value"
```

This invokes the method `.my_class_attribute=` on `MyClass`.

Comment: I typically just to an accessor if that the case either attr_reader,or attr_accessor if I want to both read and write.  In this case I modifed the code to do more than just set the internal variable (when you call this method and pass it a value it is not already it has to update another application through an API).

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do what you're talking about.  You can't change the value of `self`, so there's no class-level override for `=`.

I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to do that, though.  Scenarios in which it might be useful would require creating a new instance of the class.  You can accomplish similar things by cloning an object (via `.dup` or something) and modifying the new one, or creating a custom class method to copy an object and return a new, perhaps modified instance.  I'm speculating, but can't think of a good example.